# can i have onClick within another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I have**

```
<div>
  <div>  
     <td>
       <div></div>
     </td>
   </div>
</div>
```

**But I want to check whether I am clicking the "child div" of "td"**

```
onclick:function(e){
    tableValue = "";
    if(idvalue != 0) {
        $('#'+idvalue).css('background-color', 'transparent');
        if(idvalue == "id-8" || idvalue == "id-9")
        {
            $('#id-8').css('background-color', 'transparent');
            $('#id-9').css('background-color', 'transparent');
        }
    }
    idvalue = e.target.getAttribute('id');


    $(".border-Class > div").click(function () {
        var arr = [];
        arr = idvalue.split('-');
        switch(arr[1])
        {
            case "0": value = "border: 0 !important";
                break;
            case "1": value = "border-left: 1 !important;border-right: 0 !important;border-top: 0 !important;border-bottom: 0 !important";
                break;
            case "2": value = "border-right: 1 !important;border-left: 0 !important;border-top: 0 !important;border-bottom: 0 !important";
                break;
            case "3": value = "border-top: 1 !important;border-left: 0 !important;border-right: 0 !important;border-bottom: 0 !important";
                break;
            case "4": value = "border-bottom: 1 !important;border-left: 0 !important;border-top: 0 !important;border-right: 0 !important";
                break;
            case "5": value = "border-top: 1 !important;border-bottom: 1 !important;border-left: 0 !important;border-right: 0 !important";
                break;
            case "6": value = "border-left: 1 !important;border-right: 1 !important;border-top: 0 !important;border-bottom: 0 !important";
                break;
            case "7": value = "border: 1 !important";
                break;
            case "8": value = "border: 1 !important";
                tableValue = "cross";
                break;
            case "9": value = "border: 1 !important";
                tableValue = "cross";
                break;
        }
        $(idvalue).css('background-color', 'pink');
        if(idvalue == "id-8" || idvalue == "id-9") {
            $('#id-8').css('background-color', 'pink');
            $('#id-9').css('background-color', 'pink');
        }

    });
    this.value(value);
```

**Onclick call when i click within any one of that hierarchy. I tried in above way to confirm whether I am clicking the child div. But its not working out. 
somebody help pls?**

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is not clear at all. For a start, your js references class and id values, but your html example does not show any

Comment: Also, try to minimize the code to illustrate only the specific thing you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: you dont have valid html, tds may only have tr as parent and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question is not clear, that is probably happening because you are targeting the child `div` in `.border-Class`. That might be wrapping other divs, and the whole thing will be clickable.

If you can add a class to the child div, that might be the easiest way for you to handle the propagation:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div>  
     <td>
       <div class="click-this"></div>
     </td>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".click-this").on('click', function () {});
```